# Ubuntu 18.10 Asus GL504GV fn keys (screen and kb backlight) not working

Tags: keyboard, brightness, asus, backlight, function-keys

My main problem is that rgb keyboard lighting all day on, as there is no way to turn it off. I tried to change the settings on windows, but keyboard tunrs on after rebooting.

I tryed almost everything I found over the Internet, but no luck. Some posts suggest to manually set bright values on /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/* but in my case this directory does not exists.

```
$ ls /sys/class/leds/
asus::lightbar           input11::scrolllock  input8::kana
asus-wireless::airplane  input4::capslock     input8::numlock
input11::capslock        input4::numlock      input8::scrolllock
input11::compose         input4::scrolllock   phy0-led
input11::kana            input8::capslock
input11::numlock         input8::compose
```

Also having some trouble with modprobe

```
$ sudo modprobe asus-laptop 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'asus_laptop': No such device
```

For the screen brightness I guess i can work arround /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight values

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After some more tries I get to a good enough "solution" (at least to me)

1.- Screen brightness:

I made my own script to increase/decrease screen brightness and assign it to C^F7 and C^F8. It's not the solution I was looking for, but now I can change screen brightness

```
#!/bin/bash

BASEPATH=/sys/class/backlight
DEVICE="intel_backlight"
cd $BASEPATH
MAX=`cat ${DEVICE}/max_brightness`
CURRENT=`cat ${DEVICE}/actual_brightness`
PERCENT=`echo $MAX/100 | bc`

echo $PERCENT
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Error: wrong parameters"
    echo "Run: # set-brightness.sh inc/dec percentage"
    exit -1
fi

MODE=$1
DELTA=$2
if [ "$MODE" = "inc" ]; then
    # Increase brightness an x%
    NEW_BRIGHT="$(( $CURRENT + ( $PERCENT * $DELTA ) ))"
    if [ $NEW_BRIGHT -gt $MAX ]; then
        NEW_BRIGHT=$MAX
    fi
elif [ "$MODE" = "dec" ]; then
    # Decrease brightness an x%
    NEW_BRIGHT="$(( $CURRENT - ( $PERCENT * $DELTA) ))"
    if [ $NEW_BRIGHT -lt 0 ]; then
        NEW_BRIGHT=0
    fi
else
    echo "Option: $MODE does not exists. Please use inc or dec"
    exit -1
fi
# Set the new bright
echo $NEW_BRIGHT
echo $NEW_BRIGHT > ${DEVICE}/brightness
exit 0
```

2.- The KB problem still unsolved, but now I finally have white lights with the led bar and asus logo disabled.

To change the lights just follow the next steps

1. Open windows
2. Install Asus Aura Core from the windows store
3. Chenge the lightning setup on Asus Aura and save the changes

This way the changes are stored and loaded after booting.

Any of this "solutions" are the solutions I'm looking for, but I hope this can help others with the same issues.

Answer (score -1):

I recently got an Asus ROG GL504GV. I installed Linux Mint and W10. In W10 I have installed Aura Sync software to control RGB keyboard leds. If I apply a custom profile, it remains after rebooting even in Linux. It's not a confortable way to change leds but, at least, I am able to turn it on and off or change brightness and colors.