# how to control rgb lighting on ASUS TUG FX505DT laptop

Tags: drivers, asus, 20.10, keyboard-backlight

I recently installed ubuntu 20.10 on my laptop
Is there any way to control my laptop's built-in RGB keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want to control specifically, but here you have a few options.

1. As per [this](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/controlling-rgb-keyboard-lighting), appending `‘ acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=Linux’` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in grub, powering off, and on again, should suffice (for an explanation of `acpi_osi` you may check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110624/what-do-the-kernel-parameters-acpi-osi-linux-and-acpi-backlight-vendor-do/268106)). I would try this first, as it is the least "invasive", although I am not sure it works for RGB configuration as mentioned, or only to control the brightness level of the backlight. You would have to test which Fn keys work, see [this example](https://configurelaptop.eu/clevo-keyboard-backlight-control-for-linux/).
2. [OpenRGB](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB) is very useful.
   See also [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/02/openrgb-open-source-rgb-lighting.html).
   There is a [PPA for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/openrgb) (and Linux Mint, Pop!_OS, etc.) which has the latest OpenRGB from Git. The PPA also provides an `openrgb-dkms-drivers` package which includes the `i2c-piix4` kernel driver, so you don't have to patch the kernel in order to control the LEDs on some motherboards.

   If you need to build from source, that is explained [here](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB#linux). Make sure to also install the [Udev rules](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB#usb-access-1) to allow USB access. The Udev rules are also required if you're using the AppImage package.
3. [tuxedo-keyboard](https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/en/Infos/Help-Support/Instructions/Installation-of-keyboard-drivers-for-TUXEDO-Computers-models-with-RGB-keyboard-.tuxedo) may also be an option, check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1298400/226614).
4. There are other drivers for specific keyboards ([MSI SteelSeries](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/msi-keyboard.1.html), [Roccat](https://sourceforge.net/projects/roccat/), [Corsair](https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb), [etc.](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/595a04/what_rgb_keyboards_are_supported_and_controllable/)), but I wouldn't think they will work.

**Related**:

1. [Ubuntu 18.10 Asus GL504GV fn keys (screen and kb backlight) not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135029/ubuntu-18-10-asus-gl504gv-fn-keys-screen-and-kb-backlight-not-working)